# SFTP connection with SSH key on Ubuntu

Tags: sftp, ubuntu-16.04

I would like to give my users secure FTP access to my EC2 instance (Ubuntu Server).

These are the requirements:

1. Connection is through SSH `.pem` file
2. Connection is on port 22
3. Individual keys for each separate user
4. Using the `.pem` file, console/root access should not be allowed.

Is it possible to achieve all the above conditions?

Answer (score 3):

> 1. Connection is through SSH `.pem` file
> 2. Connection is on port 22
> 3. Individual keys for each separate user

I think it's possible if you use SFTP with public key authentication.

```
$ vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config
AuthorizedKeysFile      .ssh/authorized_keys
PasswordAuthentication  no
PermitRootLogin         no
PubkeyAuthentication    yes
```

> 4. Using the `.pem` file, console/root access should not be allowed.

```
~/.ssh/authorized_keys
command="internal-sftp" ssh-rsa AAAAXXXXX user@example.jp
```

- [OpenSSH: Difference between internal-sftp and sftp-server](https://serverfault.com/a/660325/331422)
- [sshd_config — OpenSSH SSH daemon configuration file](https://man.openbsd.org/sshd_config)